# TypeScript createProgram throwing 'ts.sys is undefined'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `createProgram`, but I'm getting `ts.sys is undefined` for this code:

```
try {
    createProgram(Utils.getFileNames(), {
        lib: ['lib.es6.d.ts']
        // target: ScriptTarget.ES5,
        // module: ModuleKind.CommonJS
    });
} catch (ex) {
    debugger;
}
```

I've tried both ways, with the commented part and with the lib option.
This is the stack trace:

```
createCompilerHost@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203082:13
createProgram@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203374:24
./src/app/docs/generator.ts/Generator.generate@http://localhost:4200/main.js:1855:13
GettingStartedComponent@http://localhost:4200/main.js:3352:9
createClass@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42397:20
createDirectiveInstance@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42284:20
createViewNodes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43504:36
createRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43418:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44449:22
debugCreateRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43936:12
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/</ComponentFactory_.prototype.create@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41764:20
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/</ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36416:16
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/</ViewContainerRef_.prototype.createComponent@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41874:28
```

Important bits:

```
createCompilerHost@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203082:13
createProgram@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203374:24
```

I'm using this example from TS' wiki page: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker

I tried searching about the issue, but could not find anything useful. Is there a package I'm missing, some configuration? I can't figure it out.

I appreciate any help...

My imports:

```
import {
    Node,
    createProgram,
    forEachChild,
    isClassDeclaration,
    isModuleDeclaration,
    TypeChecker,
    ScriptTarget,
    ModuleKind
} from 'typescript';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler library requires a compiler host to implement operations such as reading and writing files.  If you don't pass a compiler host to `createProgram`, then the library tries to create a default host automatically based on the lower-level `ts.sys` object.  `ts.sys` in turn is only automatically generated in Node.js-like environments.  So to use the TypeScript compiler library in a non-Node.js environment, you'll need to either pass your own compiler host to `createProgram` (don't worry, you only need to implement the methods you actually use) or create `ts.sys` yourself (though that is [less recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5924#issuecomment-162108399)).

Feel free to file a TypeScript issue about the poor error message if there isn't already one.

Comment: Yes, I noticed once I ran the code using node it'd work. Only through my angular app it was not working. Thank you for your help. I'll be making the necessary changes.